# Changes to TOC 1 Formatting Affects TOC 2 Formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

My situation is I need to create Word documents (Office 365) with two TOCs. Both TOCs are created from styles used in the document but different styles:

TOC 1 uses Heading 1 and Heading 2

TOC 2 uses Code Level 1, Code Level 2, and Code Level 3

The formatting of the TOCs themselves need to be different, so I modify them in the Modify dialog of the TOC fields. Specifically, the two TOCs need to use different fonts, numbering, and indentation.

The problem is that if I make a change to one of the TOCs (right-click on the TOC and choose Edit Field) the changes I make affect the other TOC. They will continue to be built from the texts using the correct styles, the but appearance of the TOC itself -- that is, the formatting of the TOC entries -- ends up being the same for both TOCs.

Is it possible to have two TOCs in the same document that are independent of the other in every regard? Both with respect to the styles used to build the TOC (which is working as I expect) as well as the appearance of the TOCs themselves (which is not working as I expect)?

Any guidance or insights would be appreciated.

Comment: You have found something that works for you, but broadly speaking auto generated ToCs all use the same set of styles so if you want completely independent styling you have to prostprocess one or more ToCs in some way, either manually or using VBA.for example, up you could create a completely new set of your own TOC level styles, and programmatically change all the ToC style names for a particular ToC to be your style names instead of the regular ones. But you have to do that every time you regenerate that ToC (AFAICR)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't like what I found but as you said it works for me. I'd be please if there was a more elegant approach.

Comment: IMO the problem really lies in the restrictive design (which is fine if the objective is to impose uniformity on ToC appearance but not so fine if that's what you wanted. To me, elegance relies on a design that would let you do something like specify 9 different styles by providing a "prefix" name and letting Word build the full style names - e.g. you say `\k "myToC" in the ToC field and Word then uses styles called "myToC 1", "myToC 2" and so on. To me, VBA solutions aren't really "elegant" and can't completely counterbalance this kind of design problem. But that's just my 2-c worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is how it is supposed to work, but it turns out if you use different numbers in the styles mapping, the desired affect can be achieved. So for the first TOC, in the Options dialog I entered 4 next to Heading 1 instead of 1, and entered 5 next to Heading 1 instead of 2. This causes it to use TOC4 and TOC5 styles in the Modify dialog. Seems kind of strange, but it works.